# Neo4j MasterClient214 could not connect to IP_ADDRESS:6001

Tags: neo4j

We've been playing around with neo4j 2.2 in HA and for some reason when our 1st server goes down and server 2 becomes the master we start to get the following error MasterClient214 could not connect to IP_ADDRESS:6001 where IP_ADDRESS is the ip address of server 1. Even after a reboot of server 1 the error still continues. The only way for everything to go back to normal is to manually fail server 2 so server 1 becomes the master again.

I am able to ping the server 1 from server2 and vice versa. I also made sure there weren't any firewall issues. Any advice on how to fix the issue or where to look would be great.

EDIT 1

Server 1

neo4j.properties

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
#neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
#neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
#neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
#neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
#neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2048M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=6144M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=10M

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=uid,email,status,approved

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true"
keep_logical_logs=7 days

# Enable online backups to be taken from this database.
online_backup_enabled=true

# Port to listen to for incoming backup requests.
online_backup_server=0.0.0.0:6362


# Uncomment and specify these lines for running Neo4j in High Availability mode.
# See the High availability setup tutorial for more details on these settings
# http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.4/ha-setup-tutorial/

# ha.server_id is the number of each instance in the HA cluster. It should be
# an integer (e.g. 1), and should be unique for each cluster instance.
ha.server_id=1

# ha.initial_hosts is a comma-separated list (without spaces) of the host:port
# where the ha.cluster_server of all instances will be listening. Typically
# this will be the same for all cluster instances.
ha.initial_hosts=PUBLIC_IP_S1:5001,PUBLIC_IP_S2:5001,PUBLIC_IP_S3:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating cluster status
# information iwth other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
#ha.cluster_server=192.168.0.1:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating transaction
# data with other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
#ha.server=192.168.0.1:6001

# The interval at which slaves will pull updates from the master. Comment out
# the option to disable periodic pulling of updates. Unit is seconds.
ha.pull_interval=1

# Amount of slaves the master will try to push a transaction to upon commit
# (default is 1). The master will optimistically continue and not fail the
# transaction even if it fails to reach the push factor. Setting this to 0 will
# increase write performance when writing through master but could potentially
# lead to branched data (or loss of transaction) if the master goes down.
ha.tx_push_factor=1

# Strategy the master will use when pushing data to slaves (if the push factor
# is greater than 0). There are two options available "fixed" (default) or
# "round_robin". Fixed will start by pushing to slaves ordered by server id
# (highest first) improving performance since the slaves only have to cache up
# one transaction at a time.
#ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#remote_shell_enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0 for all interfaces)
#remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337
#remote_shell_port=1337
```

neo4j-server.properties

```
################################################################
# Neo4j configuration
#
################################################################

# Disable authorization
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true

#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# location of the database directory
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db

# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

#
# HTTP Connector
#

# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

#
# HTTPS Connector
#

# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

# Internally generated keystore (don't try to put your own
# keystore there, it will get deleted when the server starts)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

#*****************************************************************
# Administration client configuration
#*****************************************************************

# location of the servers round-robin database directory. possible values:
# - absolute path like /var/rrd
# - path relative to the server working directory like data/rrd
# - commented out, will default to the database data directory.
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd

# REST endpoint for the data API
# Note the / in the end is mandatory
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

# REST endpoint of the administration API (used by Webadmin)
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri=/db/manage/

# Low-level graph engine tuning file
org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties


# The console services to be enabled
org.neo4j.server.manage.console_engines=shell

# Allowed values:
# HA - High Availability
# SINGLE - Single mode, default.
# To run in High Availability mode, configure the
# neo4j.properties config file, then uncomment this line:
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA

# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-server-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged


#*****************************************************************
# HTTP logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this
# property to 'true'.
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=true

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and
# archived. Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but
# changing the output format is less so, since it is configured to use the
# ubiquitous common log format
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml

# Max Threads
org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=200
```

Server 2

neo4j.properties

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
#neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
#neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
#neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
#neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
#neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M

neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=1024M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=2048M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=6144M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=512M
neostore.relationshipgroupstore.db.mapped_memory=10M

# Autoindexing

# Enable auto-indexing for nodes, default is false
node_auto_indexing=true

# The node property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
node_keys_indexable=uid,email,status,approved

# Enable auto-indexing for relationships, default is false
#relationship_auto_indexing=true

# The relationship property keys to be auto-indexed, if enabled
#relationship_keys_indexable=name,age

# Keep logical logs, helps debugging but uses more disk space, enabled for
# legacy reasons To limit space needed to store historical logs use values such
# as: "7 days" or "100M size" instead of "true"
keep_logical_logs=7 days

# Enable online backups to be taken from this database.
online_backup_enabled=true

# Port to listen to for incoming backup requests.
online_backup_server=0.0.0.0:6362


# Uncomment and specify these lines for running Neo4j in High Availability mode.
# See the High availability setup tutorial for more details on these settings
# http://neo4j.com/docs/2.1.4/ha-setup-tutorial/

# ha.server_id is the number of each instance in the HA cluster. It should be
# an integer (e.g. 1), and should be unique for each cluster instance.
ha.server_id=2

# ha.initial_hosts is a comma-separated list (without spaces) of the host:port
# where the ha.cluster_server of all instances will be listening. Typically
# this will be the same for all cluster instances.
ha.initial_hosts=PUBLIC_IP_S1:5001,PUBLIC_IP_S2:5001,PUBLIC_IP_S3:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating cluster status
# information iwth other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
#ha.cluster_server=192.168.0.1:5001

# IP and port for this instance to listen on, for communicating transaction
# data with other instances (also see ha.initial_hosts). The IP
# must be the configured IP address for one of the local interfaces.
#ha.server=192.168.0.1:6001

# The interval at which slaves will pull updates from the master. Comment out
# the option to disable periodic pulling of updates. Unit is seconds.
ha.pull_interval=1

# Amount of slaves the master will try to push a transaction to upon commit
# (default is 1). The master will optimistically continue and not fail the
# transaction even if it fails to reach the push factor. Setting this to 0 will
# increase write performance when writing through master but could potentially
# lead to branched data (or loss of transaction) if the master goes down.
ha.tx_push_factor=1

# Strategy the master will use when pushing data to slaves (if the push factor
# is greater than 0). There are two options available "fixed" (default) or
# "round_robin". Fixed will start by pushing to slaves ordered by server id
# (highest first) improving performance since the slaves only have to cache up
# one transaction at a time.
#ha.tx_push_strategy=fixed

# Enable this to be able to upgrade a store from an older version.
#allow_store_upgrade=true

# Enable this to specify a parser other than the default one.
#cypher_parser_version=2.0

# Enable shell server so that remote clients can connect via Neo4j shell.
#remote_shell_enabled=true
# The network interface IP the shell will listen on (use 0.0.0 for all interfaces)
#remote_shell_host=127.0.0.1
# The port the shell will listen on, default is 1337
#remote_shell_port=1337
```

neo4j-server.properties

```
################################################################
# Neo4j configuration
#
################################################################

# Disable authorization
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true

#***************************************************************
# Server configuration
#***************************************************************

# location of the database directory
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db

# Let the webserver only listen on the specified IP. Default is localhost (only
# accept local connections). Uncomment to allow any connection. Please see the
# security section in the neo4j manual before modifying this.
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0

#
# HTTP Connector
#

# http port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.port=7474

#
# HTTPS Connector
#

# Turn https-support on/off
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.enabled=true

# https port (for all data, administrative, and UI access)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.port=7473

# Certificate location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.cert.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.cert

# Private key location (auto generated if the file does not exist)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.key.location=conf/ssl/snakeoil.key

# Internally generated keystore (don't try to put your own
# keystore there, it will get deleted when the server starts)
org.neo4j.server.webserver.https.keystore.location=data/keystore

#*****************************************************************
# Administration client configuration
#*****************************************************************

# location of the servers round-robin database directory. possible values:
# - absolute path like /var/rrd
# - path relative to the server working directory like data/rrd
# - commented out, will default to the database data directory.
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.rrdb.location=data/rrd

# REST endpoint for the data API
# Note the / in the end is mandatory
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.data.uri=/db/data/

# REST endpoint of the administration API (used by Webadmin)
org.neo4j.server.webadmin.management.uri=/db/manage/

# Low-level graph engine tuning file
org.neo4j.server.db.tuning.properties=conf/neo4j.properties


# The console services to be enabled
org.neo4j.server.manage.console_engines=shell

# Allowed values:
# HA - High Availability
# SINGLE - Single mode, default.
# To run in High Availability mode, configure the
# neo4j.properties config file, then uncomment this line:
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA

# Comma separated list of JAX-RS packages containing JAX-RS resources, one
# package name for each mountpoint. The listed package names will be loaded
# under the mountpoints specified. Uncomment this line to mount the
# org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged.HelloWorldResource.java from
# neo4j-server-examples under /examples/unmanaged, resulting in a final URL of
# http://localhost:7474/examples/unmanaged/helloworld/{nodeId}
#org.neo4j.server.thirdparty_jaxrs_classes=org.neo4j.examples.server.unmanaged=/examples/unmanaged


#*****************************************************************
# HTTP logging configuration
#*****************************************************************

# HTTP logging is disabled. HTTP logging can be enabled by setting this
# property to 'true'.
org.neo4j.server.http.log.enabled=true

# Logging policy file that governs how HTTP log output is presented and
# archived. Note: changing the rollover and retention policy is sensible, but
# changing the output format is less so, since it is configured to use the
# ubiquitous common log format
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml

# Max Threads
org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=200
```

Comment: Could you please show us configuration files for both servers?

Comment: Make sure the machines are on the same subnet.

Comment: I added the neo4j.properties and neo4j-server.properties files for both servers. The only thing I did was remove our IP addresses from the files because they are public IPs.

Comment: @MicTech do you see anything that could be wrong with the above? This issue is causing errors when running cypher queries through the rest API.